# Twilio SMS sending

Tags: twilio

```
 await client.messages.create(
            {
                to: `+${userEntity.telephoneNumber}`,
                from: `+${process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER}`,
                body: `Your activation code is ${userEntity.activationCode}`,
            },
            (err, message) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                } else {
                    return this._res.status(200).json({message: message}).end()
                }
            }
        );
```

> Error: The number **+xxxxxxx** is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify **+xxxxxxx** at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.

Hi everyone. I was trying to send a message from Twilio to the user but I've got this error.Who can help me? Maybe I don't understand how does it work. Should I add a number to which I want to send a message to Twilio? Or what does this message mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is exactly what it means, you have to verify the number you want to send your message to.  The verification is done by either a call or a text.
[Twilio - Verify Phone number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified)

This will also allow you to use this number as a caller id when making a call(does not work with texting).

This is a somewhat common limitation setup for trial accounts.

Comment: I haven't tried it : [add-an-outgoing-caller-id](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids#add-an-outgoing-caller-id)  
I don't know if it will work on a trial account, or if their are other restrictions that may limit how many verified numbers you can have.

Comment: You can either verify the number. Or you can [upgrade your account](https://www.twilio.com/console/billing) and send messages to any number.

Comment: Error: RestClient has been removed from this version of the library. Please refer to https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node for more information.

Comment: `RestClient` was in the old version of the library. Try:
`const twilio = require('twilio');
const client = twilio(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);`